# LINQ Query to find minumum value from a grouping - unable to create constant of type 'X'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

As part of a complex query I need to find the minimum date of a set of Entity Framework records grouped by Id.

So my EF class might be:

```
public MyClass {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

And my data might look like this:

```
Id     CreatedDate
1      2012-01-01
1      2012-02-01
2      2013-01-01
2      2015-05-01
```

I'm trying to group the data by the `Id` property and then select the minimum `CreatedDate` for each grouping.

I thought this should be simple! and wrote:

```
var firstThing = (from r in records
                 group r by r.Id into grp
                 select new { 
                     Id = grp.Key, 
                     CreatedDate = grp.Min(x => x.CreatedDate) 
                 }).ToList();
```

But at the point I materialise the collection with the `.ToList()` I'm seeing the following exception:

> Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in System.Data.Entity.dll
>
> Additional information: Unable to create a constant value of type
>   'MyClass'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are
>   supported in this context.

I've had a dig around and think I understand that EF is having trouble with a comparison on 'MyClass' as it can't convert it to something SQL'y. But I'm not sure what aspect of this query is causing the issue.

I have seen some similar posts, but not a really noddy example and I'd like to better understand the cause to solve the problem.

Comment: Are you certain that's where your error is?  Is `records` the raw table data or is it a subsequent query?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem because this code works fine for me!! Can you show how you initialize the `records` ?

Comment: In my case, records is an IQueryable<MyClass> which I passed in as an parameter to a method. I created the records var outside the method by simply doing `context.MyClasses` the type of the `context.MyClasses` before I pass it in, is an ObjectSet<MyClass> from the EF context.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use functions like Min in a Linq-to-Entities query.

The way I would solve this problem is order each group by `CreatedDate`, then select the first item. I'm most familiar with the Fluent syntax so here's what it would look like with that, it should be easy to convert to yours:

```
var firstThing = records
    .GroupBy(r => r.ID)
    .Select(grp => grp.OrderBy(r => r.CreatedDate).FirstOrDefault())
    .ToList()
```

Comment: This seems like a sensible idea. I've switched my query to your suggestion but unfortunately I'm seeing the same error :( 
`var firstThing = (from r in records
                           group r by r.Id into grp
                           select grp.OrderBy(x => x.CreatedDate).FirstOrDefault()).ToList();`

Comment: After testing out the code it works for me using .Min, so I think D Stanley is right that your problem is elsewhere. Could you post some more code to show how you initialize records? I tried setting up a scenario similar to what you described where you pass an IQueryable<MyClass> to the method, but it still worked fine for me.